# Testing an unauthenticated user Rspec/Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I have had a look around but maybe I'm not looking in the right places. I am trying to find out how to test that a user cannot access a page whose controller has:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Ideally I would like to capture the devise message at the same time:

```
"you need to sign in or sign up before continuing"
```

I have this so far

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CampaignsController do

  it "should not allow a user be able to access without being authenticated" do
    get :index
    response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
  end
```

end

At present I get the error

```
Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
```

Campaigns Controller

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user! 

def index
  @campaigns = Campaign.all
end
end
```

In my spec helper I am calling the following

```
# Include Devise Test Helpers
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
```

controller_macros.rb

```
module ControllerMacros

def login_user
  before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in user
  end
end
end
```

I'm not calling the login_user method at this stage, so would the spec_helper call this?

How do I approach this correctly?

Comment: please post `CampaignsController`.

Comment: Seems ok to me, could you make sure you didn't call `sign_in` method somewhere (in you spec_helper?). Could we also have the code of the ApplicationController ?

Comment: updated, thinking now after your comments that you could be onto something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first look it seems ok. The problem could be caused if you run your entire suite, and depending on the place you call `login_user` it could add the `before(:each)` to *all* tests.

I understand you want to minimise typing, but generally I prefer my tests to be a little more explicit: I want to see what is going on in the spec.

So how I generally write this kind of test:

```
describe HomeController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  context "when not signed in" do
    describe "GET 'index'" do
      it "redirects to sign in" do
        get 'index'
        response.should be_redirect
      end
    end
    describe "GET 'about'" do
      it "returns http success" do
        get 'about'
        response.should be_redirect
      end
    end
  end

  context "when signed in" do
    before do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      sign_in(user)
    end
    describe 'GET :index' do
      it "returns http success" do
        get 'index'
        response.should be_success
      end
    end
    describe "GET 'about'" do
      it "returns http success" do
        get 'about'
        response.should be_success
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Yes, admitted: I am still fond of the old rspec syntax (using `should`), it reads much more natural to me.

Comment: thank you, thats a much better way of doing things, I agree with what you say about readability, it makes so much more sense and by only including the helper on the parts you want you don't risk any other tests being affected...

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
module ControllerMacros

  def login_user
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in user
  end
end
```

in rspec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CampaignsController do

  it 'for authenticate user' do
    before do
      login user
    end
  end

  it "should not allow a user be able to access without being authenticated" do
    get :index
    expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
  end
```